# How to implement variants/variations of a function

Tags: python, function

This is my very first question, so I sincerely apologize for any posting mistakes which I am sure I will make.  I did first search through previously answered questions, but I didn't find a suitable solution, although I recognize that I might not have searched using the correct terminology or keywords.

I have a general function that I would like to have evaluated quickly in Python.  It gets passed to an optimizer (fmin_cobyla), and I'd prefer for it to only take a single argument.  I'd like to be able to have the option of using different variations (variants? flavors?) of this function that might be controlled by a flag.  Since I want it evaluated quickly it doesn't make sense to have a bunch of if or case statements within the function (right?), so currently I have if statements around the definitions of the function variants:

```
if flag==1:
    def f(x):
        for i in range(0,len(x)*3,3):
            A[i:i+3,i:i+3]=1/x[i/3]*np.eye(3)
        tmp=np.linalg.solve(A,b)
        y=somecmodulefunction(tmp)
        return y
elif flag==2:
    def f(x):
        for i in range(0,len(x)*3,3):
            A[i:i+3,i:i+3]=x[i/3]*np.eye(3)
        tmp=np.linalg.solve(A,b)
        y=somecmodulefunction(tmp)
        return y
...
```

The functions are identical with the exception of one line.  Is this the right way to do it?  Is there any way to do this so that if I have 10 different variants, it's not just a long unwieldy block of code?

Comment: Add a parameter `flag` to the function, then add an `if` block to implement the different behavior. Try to follow DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: If the function needs to evaluated 10^10 times, wouldn't having if statements in the function slow down its evaluation? (I mentioned this in the original post)

Comment: Of course adding a statement would slow it down by some non-zero amount, but if you're worried about the performance hit from a simple `if boolean_value`, you should be writing the program in C.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the flag variable as an input to the function as well?

```
def f(x, flag):
    for i in range(0,len(x)*3,3):
        if flag == 1:
           A[i:i+3,i:i+3]=1/x[i/3]*np.eye(3)
        elif flag == 2:
           A[i:i+3,i:i+3]=x[i/3]*np.eye(3)
    tmp=np.linalg.solve(A,b)
    y=somecmodulefunction(tmp)
    return y
```

If there is a *default* value of `flag`, you can use, [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values):

```
def f(x, flag=1):
    for i in range(0,len(x)*3,3):
        if flag == 1:
           A[i:i+3,i:i+3]=1/x[i/3]*np.eye(3)
        elif flag == 2:
           A[i:i+3,i:i+3]=x[i/3]*np.eye(3)
    tmp=np.linalg.solve(A,b)
    y=somecmodulefunction(tmp)
    return y
```

So that, when you do, `f(10)`, function `f()` will be executed using `flag` equals to `1`.

If you want to use another `flag` value, you can simply do: `f(10,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repeat yourself as little as possible. This means only specifying the difference, which is the inversion of that expression. The rest is the same. If you want to change the way something is calculated, you then only have to make the change in one place.

```
def f(x, flag):
    for i in range(0,len(x)*3,3):
        temp = x[i/3]*np.eye(3)
        if flag-2:
            temp = 1/temp
        A[i:i+3,i:i+3] = temp
    tmp=np.linalg.solve(A,b)
    y=somecmodulefunction(tmp)
    return y
```

When `flag` is `2`, the `if` branch will not be executed, because `2-2` equals `0`, a falsey value. When `flag` is `1`, the `if` branch will be executed, because `1-2` equals `-1`, a truthy value. However, I'd recommend going with a boolean flag (i.e., expecting values of `True` or `False`), so you can just do `if flag:` and have `True` signifying that you want inversion.

Comment: I think passing `flag` is a good solution, but I find this particular implementation of its test a little obscure (something more explicit might be better): but if you do this, why not simply `A[i:i+3,i:i+3] = x[i/3]**(2*flag-3)*np.eye(3)`?